# Performance of H2O predict() function

Tags: python, performance, python-3.x, machine-learning, h2o

I'm using H2O's [Random Forest Regression](https://h2o-release.s3.amazonaws.com/h2o/rel-turan/4/docs-website/h2o-py/docs/modeling.html#h2orandomforestestimator) model in python. While evaluating its performance in terms of speed, I've compared it to scikit-learn's [RandomForestRegressor](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestRegressor.html).

The dataset consists of ~20,000 rows and 20 columns of data.

My machine runs windows with python 3.6 on it.

```
import time
import h2o
import pandas as pd
from h2o.estimators.random_forest import H2ORandomForestEstimator
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor

def timing(f):
    def wrap(*args):
        time1 = time.time()
        ret = f(*args)
        time2 = time.time()
        print('%s function took %0.3f ms' % (f.__name__ , (time2-time1)*1000.0))
        return ret
    return wrap


@timing
def predict_row(model, row):
    return model.predict(row)


# read data
h2o.init(max_mem_size = "8G")
h2o.remove_all() 
h2o_df = h2o.import_file(csv_path)
train, valid, test = h2o_df.split_frame([0.6, 0.2], seed=1234)
X = h2o_df.col_names[:-1]
y = h2o_df.col_names[-1]  


# random forest at H2O
rf_h2o = H2ORandomForestEstimator(model_id="rf_h2o_v1", ntrees=100, stopping_rounds=2, score_each_iteration=True, seed=1000000,
                             col_sample_rate_per_tree=0.3)
rf_h2o.train(X, y, training_frame=train, validation_frame=valid)


# random forest at sklearn
train_df = train[:-1].as_data_frame(use_pandas=True)
y_df = h2o_df[:,-1].as_data_frame(use_pandas=True)
y_df = y_df[y_df.index.isin(train_df.index)]
rf_sklearn = RandomForestRegressor(n_estimators=100, min_samples_leaf=3, oob_score=True, max_features=0.25)
rf_sklearn.fit(train_df, y_df)


# prediction comparison, let's take row #5 from the test set for example
row_h20 = test[5,:-1]
row_array = test[5,:-1].as_data_frame(use_pandas=True).values
rf_sklearn.predict(row_array)

# run 20 times and test performance on all iterations
for i in range(20):
    predict_row(rf_sklearn, row_array)
    predict_row(rf_h2o, row_h20)
```

When I ran this code, I get that the Random Forest by scikit-learn in **X4-5 times faster** than H2O's model (6-7 milliseconds vs. ~30 milliseconds on the fastest iterations in both cases).

 *My questions are:*

1. is that really the case? Can anyone verify that I'm not doing anything wrong? 

    I know H2O is built upon JVM, which is not supposed to be lightning fast, but I thought they would do at least as good as scikit-learn.
2. I need a super fast implementation of a predict in a regression algorithm. Does anyone have any suggestions? 
    scikit-learn / H2O are not mandatory for me, but I need something reliable.

Answer (score 1):

H2O uses data parallelism to achieve scale and efficiency, and the number of rows here is very small, so the number of parallel threads doing work is probably low.

H2O compares favorably speed-and-scale wise when there are more rows (millions +).

You can see how many threads are working by using the built-in Water Meter (on Linux), or "top" or another performance monitoring tool.  And if you open the H2O Flow Web UI, after parsing the data, you can see a detailed Frame Distribution Summary breakdown (see below).

For this example, the dataset I ingested has 43,978 rows and 31 columns.  You can see the number of chunks per column is 1.  This means my data parallelism level is only 1, and only 1 thread will be working.  H2O was designed to be efficient on larger data sets.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, did not know that. But how does it relate to a prediction of a single row?
Allow me to clarify: My code is designed to be run with thousands of API calls per second for prediction, where every prediction request is made of a single row. Sounds like what you are describing would, in this case, affect only training time and not the prediction time.

Comment: For that use case, you should export a MOJO or POJO from H2O and use that to make predictions.  They are meant for real-time one-row-at-a-time use cases.  I would not use the full H2O, it's going to have a lot of overhead for one-row-at-a-time use cases.  See http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-genmodel/javadoc/index.html

Answer (score 1):

There are a few things that I'd consider wrong with the benchmark:

- In H2O, you have `col_sample_rate_per_tree=0.3`, and in sklearn, you have `max_features=0.25`.  You should set `col_sample_rate` in H2O to the same thing as as `max_features` in sklearn.  Using fewer features in sklearn will cause sklearn to train faster.
- In sklearn, you have `min_samples_leaf=3`, but `min_rows` (the H2O equivalent) defaults to 1.  These should be set to the same value.  They both default to 1, so you should probably just leave them both at the default value.  Setting `min_samples_leaf=3` will force sklearn to stop building the tree sooner (so training will be faster).
- Do not set `stopping_rounds=2` in H2O.
- There are a number of other parameters that have different default values in sklearn vs H2O.
- I'd recommend running the benchmark with and without scoring on each iteration to see how that affects performance (referring to `score_each_iteration` in H2O and `oob_score` in sklearn).
- I'm assuming that your data contains only numeric features, but if you use a dataset that contains categorical features, sklearn will require you to one-hot encode those features, which could increase your training time quite a bit, depending on the number of levels for each categorical feature.

That said, it's still possible that sklearn can train faster than H2O on small datasets. H2O is designed with scalability in mind, so you'll start seeing the value of H2O (over other tools) when you use a bit more training data.  There is a nice plot of how H2O Random Forest compares to other tools as training size increases in this [benchmark](http://datascience.la/benchmarking-random-forest-implementations/) (screenshot below).  This is only on a single dataset, so it can't be generalized to all situations, but it's a good demonstration of how tools like sklearn start to break down as training size increases (sklearn RF runs out of memory after 1M rows in this particular benchmark).

[image]

Comment: Thank you, tested what you've written, but H2O still lags behind significantly on a one-row prediction task. 
My data has categorical features as well, I'm trying to avoid the misuse of sklearn on categoricals, that is why I've been searching for an alternative in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

The 6-7 milliseconds vs. ~30 milliseconds difference is probably due to the overhead of making REST API calls.

For making predictions in production environments, where 23ms really matters, I believe it is recommended practice to use the POJO or MOJO. You are using random forest, so should use MOJOs, as they are giving a notable speed improvement according to https://github.com/h2oai/h2o-3/blob/master/h2o-docs/src/product/howto/MOJO_QuickStart.md

If you are doing tests just to evaluate the speed of H2O, you should also do a comparison on a very large data set, or a more complicated model. E.g. if the difference is then 2.006s vs. 2.030s you can stop worrying about it, and move on to the more important things.

Comment: Thanks! but my need is to be able to reply to multiple single value prediction requests, and process them fast. There is no overhead, since I tested both models locally without any calls. 
But I'll definitely give Mojo/Pojo a try and report back with findings.

Comment: There is no "local" for H2O. When you run the Python API command it makes a REST API call and sends it to the H2O server (which is written in Java). When your H2O server is running on localhost 20ms of overhead sounds about right, doesn't it?

Comment: Yes, I see what you mean. So, in that case, sounds like I won't be able to go below this threshold.

Comment: As I said, if the 23ms overhead of a REST API call is significant overhead, you should be using the MOJO. See http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/productionizing.html for the various ways it can be used. I'd be very interested to see the results if you do try it.

Comment: OK, so I just discovered [CatBoost](https://tech.yandex.com/catboost/doc/dg/concepts/about-docpage/), which runs GBM and not Random Forest (which is what I was looking for). 
It gives me better results and does predictions in less than 1 millisecond per call. So far, recommended!

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar issue.  I had coded up my H2O predict to do one prediction at a time.  The performance was disappointing.  That's because there's a fair amount of overhead to set things up for H2O, including building the H2O dataframe.

To make things reasonable, I batched up several data rows to be predicted on at once, and now I get good performance.

The graph that Dr LeDell posted, clearly shows the various and sometimes large overhead that various platforms encounter.

The OP needs to set up the benchmark to reflect how they really expect to use the model: whether if the overhead is more important (unlikely), or if the time per prediction is more important.